# Deploying Python script into a Flutter Mobile Application

Tags: python, json, mongodb, api, flutter

I have created an algorithm in Python. I would like to create a mobile application with login, logout functionalities and also implement the python script algorithm into the mobile application. I have decided to use MongoDB for database.

What are the possible ways to achieve this?
Any other better database options for flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your algorithm written in python **along with** flutter app, but not **into** the flutter app. This can be achieved simply by creating a REST API server which provides some endpoints to do your actions like login, logout, etc.,

1. First explore about REST API.
   Here is my suggestion: https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest
   TLDR: REST API is a protocol based on HTTP which can be used to transfer data between client and the server.

In your case, Flutter App is the client and Python is going to be the server.

2. Setup REST API server with python.
   There are many frameworks out there in python for setting up REST API server. The simplest one would be **Flask**
   https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/

My suggestion on reading: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask

3. Look for consuming REST API in client (Flutter APP)
   You can go with this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Putting up all together will help you to resolve your need.